# Making thesis front

Tags: titles

I am using the following code for my thesis front:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{LOGO_UNIVERSITY.jpeg}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-10cm}
\textsc{\LARGE \\ Institute for Interesting People}\\[0.5cm]
\vspace{.5cm}
\textsc{\Large Master Thesis}\\[1.5cm]
\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries Very Smart Stuff}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
\vspace{1cm}
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
X
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisors:} \\
Y \\
Z \\
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
 {\large \textit{A thesis submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of Master of Science\\}}
\vspace{2cm}
{\large August 2014} \vfill
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

However, I would like to decrease the distance between the logo and the text "Institute for Interesting People". Using the command \vspace{-10cm} or e.g. \vspace{10cm} does not change anything. What's going on here and how can I change it?

Note: the command \HRule is defined via

```
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}.
```

Comment: Remove `\begin{figure}\centering` and `\end{figure}` that don't belong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several points in your code that could be improved, but the main problem is the `figure` environment, that doesn't belong there.

Here's a polished version. Adjust the spacings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{LOGO_UNIVERSITY.jpeg}

\vspace{1cm}

\textsc{\LARGE Institute for Interesting People}

\vspace{1cm}
\textsc{\Large Master Thesis}\\[1.5cm]
\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries Very Smart Stuff}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule

\vspace{2.5cm}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\emph{Author:}\\
X
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\emph{Supervisors:} \\
Y \\
Z \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3cm}

{\large\itshape A thesis submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements\\ 
  for the degree of Master of Science\\}

\vspace{2cm}

{\large August 2014}

\vfill

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```